# layout_constraintHorizontal_bias and layout_constraintVertical_bias

Tags: android, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I started working on improving my UI, using `constraintLayout`. while using the layout editor i found some properties i.e `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` and `layout_constraintVertical_bias`.

I don't really get their meaning or function, **what exactly are they and their functions** ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#baseline

Comment: Refer [https://www.raywenderlich.com/9193-constraintlayout-tutorial-for-android-getting-started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9193-constraintlayout-tutorial-for-android-getting-started) this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bias**

Bias is used to adjust the spacing between a view and what it is constrained to. They specifically work with centered constraint views and it can be added vertically or horizontally.

more at [here](https://pusher.com/tutorials/constraintlayout-kotlin-part-2)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find sample video that shows the usage of bias [sample](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#adjust-the-constraint-bias/).

For example if you set both horizontal constraints view is centered between 2 views (has bias set to 0.5). And you can move view more to left/right side of screen by changing bias to some value from 0 to 1.